# A seemingly simple Hibernate query is taking 15-18 seconds

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a seemingly innocent Hibernate query:

```
public List<ContentAccess> getByMemberId(
Integer memberId
) {
List<ContentAccess> contentAccess = 
getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery(
"contentAccess.member.id", 
memberId
);
return contentAccess;
}
```

contentAccess table has about 20 records and member table also has about 20 records but when the above mentioned named query is executed for each of the 20 members, it takes 15-18 seconds!

The environment is: Windows, JDK 1.5.0_09, Hibernate 3, MySQL 5.5

Any suggestions on how I can go about locating the bottleneck? Thanks!

Dilip

Answer (score 2):

firstly, we need to know what `contentAccess.member.id` contains as the query.

secondly, check if you are using batch loading  (if not there is a possibility that there are 21 queries being fired ).. one query for each related record in the member table plus the original query.

you can also try to modify the query to use `joins`, this can improve performance ..

having said all that.. we can give you a (possibly) better solution if we can get hold of the query which is being fired and mapping of referenced pojos..

Comment: It's as simple as the following:

Comment: @NamedQuery(
     name="contentAccess.member.id", 
     query="from ContentAccess contentAccess where contentAccess.member.id = ?")

Comment: ContentAccess.java has fields such as the following:
 private int id;
 private Member member;
 private ContentCombo contentCombo;
 private Date startDate;
 private Date endDate;
 

The Member class is quite ordinary with mostly primary variables.

ContentCombo.java has collection fields such as the following:
 private Set<Syllabus> syllabi = new HashSet<Syllabus>();
 private Set<Language> languages = new HashSet<Language>();
 private Set<Grade> grades = new HashSet<Grade>();
 private Set<Subject> subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();

Comment: in your hibernate.cfg.xml set <property name="showSql">true</property> and <property name="formatSql">true</property> to figure out if the system, is firing multiple queries.. and read this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch .. it will help you use batching or another technique to improve performance.